# Regex: convert a string to a dictionary using dict comprehension and regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, list-comprehension

I a have a string which i want to convert to a dictionary. What i want to do is select the uppercase chars as keys for the dictionary and count them up as values. If an uppercase char is followed by a lowercase (or several ones in a row), it should go as a new key. Assume the string is `IIrIIrIrIrIIrIIrIrIrII`, then the output should be the following:
`{'I': 6, 'Ir': 8}`. Instead, I get `{'Ir': 8, 'I': 14}`.

This is what i have:

```
def convert(string):
    return {el: string.count(el) for el in re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', string)}
```

I got stuck at the regex part. If the string were to be `AIrAIrIrIrAIrAIrIrIrAA`, then I get the correct output.

Pls help,
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def convert(string):
    return Counter(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', string))
```

Example:

```
>>> convert('IIrIIrIrIrIIrIIrIrIrII')
Counter({'Ir': 8, 'I': 6})
```

You can wrap that return in `dict()` if you don't want to return a `Counter`. Or just do it outside the function if you need to.

The problem in your code is that the count is coming from checking `string.count(thing)`, so you're counting *all* the `'I'`'s, including the ones that are part of `'Ir'`.

Comment: I didn't know about the existence of Counter. Thank you, I've learned a new thing :)